# Inserting some columns from one table to another and including current date as well MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

I have a MySQL database with two tables as displayed here:

[Balance Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgiSZ.png)

```
Id: int [PK] AutoIncrementing
AccountId: Varchar(100) 
UserBalance: Double
DateEntered: Date
```

[Account Table (private info censored)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Jpu.png)

```
AccountId: Varchar(100) [PK] Not AutoIncrementing
Email: Varchar(45)
Balance: Double
Role: Varchar(5)
Username: Varchar(45)
HasInvested: Tinyint(1)
```

What I want to do is take the AccountIds and Balances of all rows from the Account Table and insert them into the equivalent columns in the Balance Table which I have already done with the following code:

```
use database;
insert into balance (AccountID, UserBalance)select AccountId, Balance from account
```

however I also want the code to automatically fill in the DateEntered columns of each row in the Balance table with the current date using the CURDATE() Function when executed. How should I alter my code to do this?

Comment: Well if that sql actually works, then simply `insert into balance (AccountID, UserBalance,DateEntered) select AccountId, Balance, CURDATE() from account`

Comment: Huh. Thought I already tried that but guess I did it incorrectly somewhere. Thanks for the help and the edit.

Comment: `UserBalance: Double`  OT:  Double is an approximate type and not suitable for currency. For anything that requires precision, used a fixed type like `decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

> however I also want the code to automatically fill in the `DateEntered` columns of each row in the `Balance` table with the current date using the `CURDATE()` Function when executed. How should I alter my code to do this?

You don't have to do this. You must simply set DEFAULT value for this column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Balance
    ALTER COLUMN DateEntered DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Now, if this column is not mentioned in INSERT query or the keyword `DEFAULT` is used as a value for this column, the column will be set with current datatime value automatically.

[Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

There is a little problem - this cannot be applied to DATE column, it ia applicable only to DATETIME and TIMESTAMP. But I think that simplification may be more important that small row size increasing.

---

If you need in the column whose datatype is DATE strictly then you may add autoutilized column and make `DateEntered` column generated:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Balance
    ADD COLUMN created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
UPDATE Balance SET created_at = DateEntered;
ALTER TABLE Balance
    DROP COLUMN DateEntered,
    ADD COLUMN DateEntered DATE AS (DATE(created_at)) VIRTUAL;
```

But in this case you cannot edit the value of this column (edit `created_at` column, and the value of `DateEntered` will be changed automatically) or insert into this column (you cannot mention it in the columns list in INSERT query).

---

If you need this column to be DATE strictly then I recommend to create a trigger which sets the value for this column if it is not specified:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_balance
BEFORE INSERT ON Balance
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.DateEntered = COALESCE(NEW.DateEntered, CURRENT_DATE);
```

The value will be set to current date only if the value is not specified in the query explicitly or if NULL is specified.